# 404 Not Found when deploying Jersey App on Wildfly 10

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, wildfly

I have a Jersey Application running on Wildfly. In my local environment (Wildfly 9), it runs without problems.
When I try to run it in the Production server (Wildfly 10), it's deployed with no harm, but when I try to access (via browser or REST client), I'm getting 404 not found.

The endpoint I'm trying to access:
http://:28080/mycompany-webservice2/dieta/getMessage

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <!-- <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name> -->
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mycompany</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <!-- <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name> -->
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Resource Class:

```
package com.mycompany.resources;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/dieta")
public class DietaResource {
    @Path("/getMessage")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getMessage() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson("It works!");
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany-webservice2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--name>mycompany-webservice2</name-->

    <repositories>
      <!-- Repository for EclipseLink artifacts -->
      <repository>
        <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
        <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
      </repository>    

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
      <!-- For the annotation processor plugin -->
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-annotation-plugin</id>
        <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>mycompany-webservice2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.1</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>eclipselink-jpa-metamodel</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-public_review</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
           <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>  
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>  
            <version>2.5.2</version>  
            <scope>provided</scope>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: try with <url-pattern>/mycompany-webservice2/*</url-pattern> in servlet declaration.

Comment: @jcrada didn't work this way

Comment: Have you removed the JAX-RS subsystem? WildFly uses RESTEasy for it's JAX-RS implementation. Also those hibernate dependencies should marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins, I'll try that!